# CSS: SVG as content works for Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

In Firefox the SVG icon won't display. It is displayed in every other browser. Any idea why? Is this not meant to be supported?

HAML

```
.contact-form__error
  .contact-form__error--icon
  .contact-form__error--text Something went wrong. Please try again later.
```

CSS

```
.contact-form__error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.contact-form__error--icon {
  // content: image-url('icons/alert_error.svg');
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin-right: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.contact-form__error--text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Lightheaded/pen/NGZWyj

Comment: Well the `content` property should only be used for pseudo-elements. I guess Chrome is less strict about it than FF. [**MDN Ref: Content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach it on :before or :after instead

```
.contact-form__error--icon:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQqbbM

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't figure out it on my own. If you could please link the MDN reference posted by Paulie_D in a reply to the original post, it would be an even more complete answer. Thanks!